Assets Not Loading or Disorganized on Page Builder Pages with Interactivity API
When using a page builder to create a page, the necessary assets (CSS, JS, etc.) do not load automatically.
I am leveraging WordPress Interactivity API SSR without introducing any additional logic.
The problem becomes more pronounced when interacting with the Interactivity API, especially with the data-wp-router-region attribute. In such cases, assets may load improperly, resulting in broken functionality or inconsistencies.
Demo: https://bsf.d.pr/v/yv4ZUe
Furthermore, JavaScript features that depend on initial page load events like DOMContentLoaded or window.load may fail to work as expected. This happens because these events have already been triggered, leaving the dynamically added content unaware of them.
Could you suggest any workarounds to resolve this issue?

This question is similar to: How to handle JavaScript reinitialization for dynamically loaded AJAX content with WordPress script dependencies?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Yes, it is different. I have update the question @mmm
